# How to analyze reply from server using QtWebkit?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I am a beginner in Qt...

In my program i have a **Qwebview** which i try to access some site.

how can i **analyze the request** the user giving to the server? for example: user submitting a form..

and **how can i analyze the reply coming from server**...? for example: server replies by streaming a audio file to the browser when the user submit a form..and i want to capture those audio streams for analyzing it.

Any help?
Thank u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom [network access manager](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and set it for your web page (see [QWebPage::setNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebpage.html#setNetworkAccessManager)). In this special implementation, create a custom network reply which proxies the data, see this [mirror tool](http://gitorious.org/qtwebkit/performance/blobs/master/host-tools/mirror/main.cpp) for an example implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of  the class [QWebInspector](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebinspector.html)

If you have already developed front-end, probably it looks familiar with the "Chrome Developer Tools" or "Safari Web Inspector", in fact, both browsers are powered by WebKit, and this tool is the WebInspector (http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector)

Have a nice debugging